# Execute matlab m file from console application

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am trying to run a matlab m file I have created from my c# console application.

I have added a reference to the Matlab Application (Version 8.2) Type Library after looking at the example on Mathworks, [MathWorks Example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html). This is fine however I still do not see how I can execute my m file to run using MLApp.

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
```

Comment: Is using System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo and you open it from MAtlab.exe, what you want?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. In my console application I want to execute my m-file. Something like matlab.Execute("c:\my_matlab\my_m_file.m")